# How to parse values from multiple lines into a single array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, dataset

I'm trying to put specific variables from a chunk of text into a single array for example the raw data:

```
dataset1
    <Time>08/30/2016 00:08:44.568</Time>
    <Tag>01234/<Tag>
    <Runs>2</Runs>
    <ID>A0 04 78 C1 02</ID>
    <Count>4</Count>
    <Kind>134</Kind>
enddataset1
dataset2
    <Time>08/30/2016 00:08:34.568</Time>
    <Tag>12345</Tag>
    <Runs>3</Runs>
    <ID>A0 04 78 C1 02</ID>
    <Count>1</Count>
    <Kind>140</Kind>
enddataset2
```

And I'd like to put it into an array as such

```
08/30/2016 00:08:44.568 \t 01234 \t 2 \t A0 04 78 C1 02 \t 4 \t 134
08/30/2016 00.08:34.568 \t 12345 \t 3 \t A0 04 78 C1 02 \t 1 \t 140
```

The descriptors (i.e. Time, Tag, Runs, etc) are constant and the values between them are variable.

Any knowledge on how to pull from within?

Comment: I'd use an XML library to read the input (e.g. XML::LibXML) and Text::CSV to write the output.

Comment: Is that your actual text? Because it's almost XML. But almost XML that isn't XML is Evil.

Comment: simple homework for stack users?

Comment: Yes, the exact almost XML text @Sobrique thee evilest

Comment: I think a rolled up copy of the XML spec, being used to slap whoever wrote it around the head, is the only really appropriate answer at that point

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a quick and dirty solution you can do the following:

```
while ($s=~/dataset\d*\s*(.*?)\s*end ?dataset\d*/gs) {
    my $r=$1;
    my @a=$r=~m{<\w+>(.*?)</\w+>}g;
    print join("\t",@a),"\n";
}
```

The code assumes that all the input is stored in the variable `$s` (i.e. in memory). Your formatting is slightly incosicistent (e.g. `enddataset1` vs `end dataset`), so you might have to tweak my regular expressions a little bit.

Comment: The datasets contain multiple series of these "paragraphs" will the quick and easy one-liner allow for multiple arrays if I print within a loop?

Comment: No, you have to provide some more details for that (e.g. give an example with at least two paragraphs).

Comment: Sorry, changed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Provided your data is consistent. This will work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in,"<",$ARGV[0]) or die "File $ARGV[0] open error:$!\n";
my @in = <$in>;
close($in);

foreach my $in(@in) {
    chomp($in);
    if($in=~/enddataset/) {
        print "\n";
    }   
    elsif($in=~/dataset/) {
        #do nothing
    }   
    elsif ($in=~/<.*>(.*)<\/.*>/) {  #get data between tags
        print "$1\t";
    }   
}
```

Comment: if it worked you may accept/upvote the answer that helped you @89pies

Comment: definitely up-voted but I don't have enough credit yet apologies

Comment: @89pies i didnt notice btw no need to apologize

Answer (score 0):

> *I am not encouraging these type of codings unless temporarily solution.*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile = "input.txt";

open(IN, $inputfile) || die "Couldn't read..: $!..\n";
local $/; $_ = <IN>; my $temp = $_;
close(IN);

my @arrays = (); my $joinVals = "";
while($temp=~m/dataset(\d+)((?:(?!enddataset\1).)*)enddataset\1/sg)
{
    my $tags = $&;
    $tags=~s/<([a-z0-9\-\_]*)>((?:(?!<\/\1>).)*)<\/\1>/ $joinVals .= "$2\t";  ($&);/ieg;
    $joinVals .= "\n";
}

my @storearr = split /\n/i, $joinVals;
print join "\n", @storearr;
```

> *May be someone can simplify this above coding*.